# rake db:migrate is being aborted due to rake version difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake-task

I am getting the error

```
rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.1.0. Using bundle exec may solve this.
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/iang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `require'
/Users/iang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `rescue in require'
/Users/iang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
/Users/iang/code/Projects/work/startco/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/iang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
/Users/iang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
/Users/iang/code/Projects/work/startco/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/iang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
/Users/iang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
/Users/iang/code/Projects/work/startco/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/iang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

used bundle and it did not fix the problem... any ideas as to help fix this problem?

Comment: skipped over the "exec" part, runing "bundle exec rake db:migrate" worked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Or, if you're using Rails 4 binstubs:

```
./bin/rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Could you help me understand the nature of the error message, though? On my rails applications, usually running the `rake` command works fine - but on a recent tutorial project, I ran into this issue and don't understand why (Rails 4.0.1, Ruby 2.0.0, Gem 2.0.3 running on Ubuntu 12.04). Did I unwittingly 'activate' a newer rake? (How do I do that?) and why does it confuse the interpreter/Gemfile?

Comment: Sure. Gems have different versions (as you know). The Rails app is requesting Rake version x, but Rake version y is first in the load path. So Ruby can't activate the correct version. Bundler solves this.

Answer (score 30):

I hit the same error. Running `bundle update` solved it.

**Update:** As suggested by TuK `bundle update rake` is the way to go.

Comment: Yep - this solves the mismatched version error message. It's the right answer!

Comment: Running `bundle update` may update more than desired. Running `bundle update rake` will only update rake.

Comment: Thx TuK, sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error message while deploying to production with capistrano.  To fix it I executed the following on my production server:

```
gem update rake
```

Comment: I used `gem uninstall rake`. You will be prompted for the version you want uninstall. that helped me to revert to 10.1.0. Anyway @Goodfellow's idea helped me to find this, so +1

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

`bundle update rake` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but running `bundle update rake` didn't work for me. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116052/1068150) worked for me. You have to remove your Gemfile.lock:

```
rm Gemfile.lock
```

then re-bundle:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
Why we got this error? 
For the rake version of our OS is different from the version of our project. **When we set the same. Everything gets ok!**

The light way is set the same version in our Gemfile. And make sure keep all the project the same rake!

```
gem 'rake', '10.2.2' #forking error! force the version the same with our OS and all projects!!!
```

I hope U see what I said and the real reason of this error. Then we will have more resolutions  such as "bundle update rake". Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

just install old version by command: gem install rake -v '10.1.0'